# MUI Button how to remove extra space inside the button?

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to make a small button, but there's whitespace inside the button that I can't seem to get rid of. Tried setting max width, and set margin and padding to 0, but nothing seems to work.

```
<Button size={"small"} sx={{ m: 0, p: 0, maxWidth: "10px" }}>
  <MoreVertIcon />
</Button>
```

The button is inside a `Stack` component with `direction={'row'}`, and I've verified that the space does not come from its container, it's inside the button.

How can I get rid of all the purple areas?

[image: button with extra space]

Comment: Can you add more detail, `whitespace inside the button` needs clarification

Comment: it might be better to use iconButton in this case

Comment: @Jeremy thanks I was referring to the purple region in the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Set the `minWidth` param to 0

```
<Button size={"small"} sx={{ m: 0, p: 0, minWidth:0 }}>
  <MoreVertIcon />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using this https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/#buttons-with-icons-and-label and something like https://mui.com/material-ui/api/icon/, in which case the white space / padding is there to help you.

To remove it you would need to use a css selector in your stylesheet and remove the css which is provided to the icon or button (probably icon).

CSS rules for the button are here https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/#css and for the icon its probably here https://mui.com/material-ui/api/icon/#css

Have a dig around the html elements in the chrome console and change css rules / learn which are going to have the desired affect. I doubt that you want to remove this padding / white space though. If you do it will be something like `padding: 0` when you have selected the icon.